# Replace elements in an array field in mongodb in allrecords

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, replaceall

```json
{
    "_id": ObjectId("60743bd0ffb98b1e7c215c1b"),
    "orderId": "787968",
    "notes":"Leave in porch"
    "lineItems": [
        {
            "lineItemId": "1741547",
            "channelLineItemId": "9741370294381",
            "skuId": "XXX-YYY-x-PR-YYY"
        },
        {
            "lineItemId": "1741549",
            "channelLineItemId": "9741370359917",
            "skuId": "XXX-YYY-x-PR-YYY"
        },
        {
            "lineItemId": "1741551",
            "channelLineItemId": "9741370425453",
            "skuId": "XXX-YYY-x-P-YYY"
        }
    ],
    "Data": {
        "email_status": "SENT",
        "sent_date": ISODate("2021-04-12T12:23:48.623Z")
    }
}
```

I had a Collection **orderData** in my mongo with the above structure.

I need to replace all `-PR-` and `-PG-` with a simple hyphen `-` in all records and in all lineitems. ie, it needs to loop through all the records and all the array elements.
if I am using a SQL command I will be using

`update line_item set sku_id = replace(sku_id , '-PR-','-');`

after executing the command the **XYZ-BCD-X-PR-ZAB** will be
**XYZ-BCD-X-AB**

I know how to update the elements outside to the array, if I am trying to replace command in notes I can use

```js
db.orderData.find().forEach(function(doc) {
    doc.note : doc.note.replace('-PG-', '-');
    db.orderData.save(doc);
});
```

I don't know how to use the same in updating in an array

I had tried

```js
db.orderData.find({orderId : "787968"}).forEach(function(doc) {
    doc.lineItems.$.skuId : doc.lineItems.$.skuId.replace('-PG-', '-');
    db.orderData.save(doc);
});
```

but it is not working.

Someone, please help me and thanks in advance.

Comment: in what fields you want to do this? only in `skuId` ?

Answer (score 4):

You can do this through putting an aggregation pipeline in the `update`:

1. use `$addFields` to `$map` the `lineItems` array;
2. use `$replaceAll` in the `$map` to replace **-PR-** with **-**
3. repeat step 2 for replace **-PG-** with **-* in another `$addFields` stage

```js
db.collection.update({
  _id: ObjectId("60743bd0ffb98b1e7c215c1b")
},
[
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "lineItems": {
        $map: {
          input: "$lineItems",
          as: "l",
          in: {
            lineItemId: "$$l.lineItemId",
            channelLineItemId: "$$l.channelLineItemId",
            skuId: {
              "$replaceAll": {
                "input": "$$l.skuId",
                "find": "-PR-",
                "replacement": "-"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "lineItems": {
        $map: {
          input: "$lineItems",
          as: "l",
          in: {
            lineItemId: "$$l.lineItemId",
            channelLineItemId: "$$l.channelLineItemId",
            skuId: {
              "$replaceAll": {
                "input": "$$l.skuId",
                "find": "-PG-",
                "replacement": "-"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Here is the [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/qTTfQygCcSr) for your reference.

---

Update as OP using Mongo DB 3.6

As `$replaceAll` is only available starting from Mongo DB 4.4, the `$replaceAll` could have been replaced by below workaround:

1. `$split` by `-PR-` or `-PG-` to break into array of segments
2. rejoin the array by `$reduce` and `{$concat: ["$$value","-","$$this"]}`
3. For this case, 2 extra hyphens will be introduced in the `$concat`. Use `$substrCP` to cut the 2 heading hyphens.

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "lineItems": {
        $map: {
          input: "$lineItems",
          as: "l",
          in: {
            lineItemId: "$$l.lineItemId",
            channelLineItemId: "$$l.channelLineItemId",
            skuId: {
              "$reduce": {
                "input": {
                  "$split": [
                    "$$l.skuId",
                    "-PR-"
                  ]
                },
                "initialValue": "",
                "in": {
                  $concat: [
                    "$$value",
                    "-",
                    "$$this"
                  ]
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "lineItems": {
        $map: {
          input: "$lineItems",
          as: "l",
          in: {
            lineItemId: "$$l.lineItemId",
            channelLineItemId: "$$l.channelLineItemId",
            skuId: {
              "$reduce": {
                "input": {
                  "$split": [
                    "$$l.skuId",
                    "-PG-"
                  ]
                },
                "initialValue": "",
                "in": {
                  $concat: [
                    "$$value",
                    "-",
                    "$$this"
                  ]
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      lineItems: {
        "$map": {
          "input": "$lineItems",
          "as": "l",
          "in": {
            lineItemId: "$$l.lineItemId",
            channelLineItemId: "$$l.channelLineItemId",
            skuId: {
              "$substrCP": [
                "$$l.skuId",
                2,
                1000000// just some very big number
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ])
```

Here is the [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/UVEPLyyq9AU) for your reference.

Comment: it can become smaller with 1 $map i think like [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/4Yj2k6E2f4d)

Comment: Thanks @Takis_ Thats a good point. I think OP should use your concise version in his actual code. I would just keep my slightly tedious version for the demonstration purpose in SO here.

Comment: my mongo is version 3.6, I think replaceAll function is not available in that version. is there any function that can support that version 3.6

Comment: I updated the answer with an alternative using `$split`, `$concat`, `$reduce`, `$strLenCP`, which should be available in MongoDB 3.6